# Puppet: set default values for nested hashes

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am creating a class which creates a ssh keys pair for users.

In Hiera it looks like this:

```
ssh::default_user_keys::entries:
  root:
    privkey: ENC[PKCS7,MIIH/QYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIH7jCCB+oCAQAx...]
    pubkey: BiQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBejCCAXYC...
  user1:
    privkey: ENC[PKCS7,MIIH/Bf0mv0aa7JRbEWWONfVMJBOX2I7x...]
    keydir: /srv/data/user1/.ssh
  user2:
    privkey: ENC[PKCS7,MIIBiQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBejCCAXYCAQAx...]
    keytype: id_ecdsa
```

If some values are not specified in Hiera, they must be picked up from default values in the manifest.

So my question is how to write the manifest correctly?
This is my pseudo code I try to make working:

```
class ssh::default_user_keys_refact (
  Hash $entries = lookup('ssh::default_user_keys_refact::entries', "merge" => 'hash'),
) {
  $entries.each |String $user, Hash $item = {} | {

    set_default { $item:
      privkey => undef,
      pubkey  => undef,
      keydir  => "/home/${user}/.ssh",
      keytype => id_rsa,
      comment => undef,
    }
    
    $sshpriv = $item[privkey]
    file { "${keydir}/$[keytype}":
      ensure  => file,
      owner   => $user,
      mode    => '0600',
      content => $sshpriv,
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have ideas how to make this pseudo code working? Or in other words, how to set up default values for nested hiera hash in puppet manifest?

puppet versions is 6.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you expect the values not to be specified or the keys not to be specified in the hash in Hiera? Also, will the structure for each key-value pair in the hash in Hiera, be consistent, or will different hashes contain different keys and/or value types?

Comment: Each user has at least one key-value pair in Hiera. It's a ssh private key (privkey). 
The  keys 'keytype' and 'keydir' can be specified in hiera, but if not, they should take default values.
Other keys are not allowed.
Some keys like 'comment' or 'pubkey' don't have default values, but they can be specified by hiera.
So I have 5 key-value pair, but only one is mandatory in hiera (privssh) and only two should have default values on the manifest (keydir and keytype).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or in other words, how to set up default values for nested hiera hash in puppet manifest?

The fact that the hashes for which you want to provide defaults are nested inside others in the Hiera data isn't much relevant, because at the point of use they have been plucked out.  With that being the case, you can accomplish this fairly easily by leveraging Puppet (not Hiera) [hash merging](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/lang_data_hash.html#merging-hashes).  It might look something like this:

```
$entries.each |String $user, Hash $props| {

  # Merge with default values
  $full_props = { 
    'keydir'  => "/home/${user}/.ssh",
    'keytype' => 'id_rsa'
  } + $props

  file { "${full_props['keydir']}/${full_props['keytype']}":
    ensure  => 'file',
    owner   => $user,
    mode    => '0600',
    content => $full_props['privkey'],
  }
}
```

That's by no means the only way, but it's clean and clear, and it scales reasonably well.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that the merge would override the values from Hiera instead of providing defaults because kv from the second argument replaces kv from the first argument. If you change the arguments' order in the merge, then this should work.

Comment: Do you mean I need to use a conctruction $props + { } instead of { } + $props?

Comment: @AleksandrMakhov, the correct construction is shown in the answer already (`{ } + $props`).  I edited to make that correction after Matt commented.  But I also provided a link to the documentation for this feature.  Read that to satisfy yourself that what is shown is indeed correct.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks I've already tested it and it works great.
Thanks a lot for your help.